# Using preventDefault with prompt

Tags: jquery, prompt, preventdefault

I have a multi-select list that calls a function to open a prompt for each selected item in the list. It works fine but the Prevent Duplicate message is displayed in the prompt. Is there a way to prevent that? I found this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b3q666y2/1/) that shows the problem.

The line loading my function is

```
<input type="submit" name="Edit Options" value="Edit Options" id="edit_options" onclick="javascript:return EditOptions();  return false;">
```

My function is the same as shown in the jsfiddle except that the list is read in to provide the prompts arguments.

Answer (score 0):

```
 onclick="javascript:return EditOptions();  return false;"
```

You have to returns.  The second return is never executed.

```
 onclick="javascript:EditOptions();  return false;"
```

would work, assuming EditOptions() doesn't error out.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the double return mistake. Unfortunately, removing the first one didn't make a difference and prevent duplicate message is still there.

Answer (score -1):

The checkbox you are seeing in the second prompt onwards is a feature in the Chrome browser. It is there to enable users to get out of an ongoing, annoying stream of alerts and prompts, since prompts prevents the user from doing anything on the web page, including closing it.

> To get around it, you could try a 1 second interval between the
>   prompts, but this is an ugly workaround.

**Edit:** This workaround doesn't seem to work anymore, which is good from a user's point of view. There is nothing you can do to get around the browser feature.

#### Alternate prompt solution

Prompts and alerts are these ugly fossils from the early days of the internet and should generally be avoided. A better solution is to use modals, which are non-interrupting alerts, created only inside your HTML instead of by the user's browser.

There are several frameworks that can assist you with modals, for example jQuery UI and Bootstrap. If you want, you can CSS the hell out of these guys to your liking - contrary to the browser's prompts, which are just plain dull as well as limited in size and behavior.

Comment: I had originally tried using a dialog. The problem is that, the way I understand it, is that the code for the dialog needs to be created first. I couldn't find a way to adjust it based on the number of selected entries in the list. So if I create the form and have 10 input fields in it and five list items are selected, it works fine. But if 11 items are selected, one gets lost. There may be a way to dynamically change that but I needed to get this going and thought the prompt method would be the quickest way of doing that.

Comment: There should be no problems adding input fields dynamically with JS, there are loads of tutorials for this on the internet. However, since you have decided upon using prompts, my answer still stands: your problem with the checkbox in the prompt is caused by a browser feature, with a possible workaround using a 1 second interval between showing the prompts.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: I just tested this, and it seems the 1 second interval does not help anymore. I don't think any interval helps, because unless I reload the page, the checkbox shows up even when minutes have passed after the first. The functionality is there to help the user and prevent them from getting stuck, so I don't think there are any workarounds to that checkbox.